# Which interface does this type implement?

Tags: import, go, interface, declare

In essence, four questions are here for Golang interfaces, with each one slightly harder than the one before it.

1. say we imported a lot of interfaces, A, B, C, ..., G

import (
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        // more ...
        "G"
    )

and we define a type S:

```
type S struct {
    // more ...
}
```

now if S "implements" one of the interfaces:

```
func (s S) Foo() {
    // more ...
}
```

Up to date, is there any other way to tell which interface of A - G does S implement, except for looking and searching into interface declarations of A - G? If no, is there a way to explicitly tell S to implement which interface? So far, it appears that the which interface S implemented is inferred.

2. If, for the same example, B, C, D interfaces all have the Foo() method with the same signature. In this case, which interface does S implement? Does it depend on the order those interfaces are imported from B, C, and D?
3. If, rather than importing interfaces, we declare and define interfaces B, C, D in the same file, but those interfaces again all have Foo() method with the same signature, which interface does S implement? Does it depend on the order those interfaces are declared, or defined?
4. If, we declared and defined B, C, D interfaces in the same file, B has Foo() method, C has Bar() method, and D has both Foo() and Bar(). Now if S implement Foo() and Bar(), then does S implement B and C, or S only implements D?

Comment: You introduced another wrinkle in your question, possibly accidentally, by making your method `foo()` (private) not `Foo()`. [Interfaces with private methods can't be implemented in the usual way by types in packages other than the one where they were defined.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/6hpUErAfMHI/X0bHeoZyfz0J)

Comment: As I think hobbs was getting at, your third question seems to use 'same file' to mean 'same package', but packages are often multiple files.

Comment: [The spec on interface types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) may be useful. You can always try to assign an instance of some concrete `T` to a variable `var i I` (or `var i pkg.I`) to test a theory, or at runtime, use [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switches](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to work with an interface variable.

Comment: @twotwotwo I just interpreted `foo` as though it was `Foo`, didn't really think about the public/private implication. I think it's a reasonable assumption that Bruce *wasn't* trying to make that particular distinction, although it's worth noting :)

Comment: Yea you are right, it should be Foo instead of foo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. No. (But as a side note, you don't import interfaces, you import packages.)
2. All of them. Order doesn't matter. If you declared variables of type `B`, `C`, and `D`, all of them would be able to hold an `S`.
3. All of them. What you do in the same or different files doesn't matter.
4. All of them. `S` implements `B` because `S` has `Foo()`. `S` implements `C` because `S` has `Bar()`. `S` implements `D` because `S` has both `Foo()` and `Bar()`.

Comment: Thanks, hobbs. While this makes sense, it raise another question. If B, C, or D has more than one method like Foo(), but S only implements Foo(), not the others, then would you still say type B can hold an S? It seems an "incomplete implementation" of an interface.

Comment: @Bruce a type that doesn't implement all of the methods in an interface doesn't implement the interface.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems that I forgot to include that case in my question. So for question 4 if S only implements Foo() method then S only implements B interface, but not D because D has an extra Bar() that is not implemented. Right? I'll accept the answer once all are justified, very likely soon! Thanks.

Comment: @Bruce: yes, that's right. This seems like a roundabout way to get to the answer versus reading parts of the spec (linked from a comment on your question) and/or making a few files and seeing if they compile.